# FileReader error/unwanted output, when reading two files and writing to one in Java

Tags: java, filereader, shuffle

What I am trying to achieve is to read two files, randomise the order of the strings in each of the files and then add them together into a new blank file. I am able to read in the files and randomise them, however when it comes to combining the two files together I receive unwanted output after the strings such as: 
NAME1java.io.FileReader@78ef430bCOMPANY2java.io.FileReader@d80ba6ff

(Obviously the parts I don't want are the ***java.io.FileReader@d80ba6ff*** parts and the characters after the @ are always random)

I only seem to read in one line of each of the files as well

Here is my main method where I combine the files together

```
ReadFiles obj = new ReadFiles();
    obj.loadCompanies();
    obj.loadTitles();

    FileReader fCompany=new FileReader("F:\\company2.txt");
    FileReader fTitle=new FileReader("F:\\title2.txt");
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fCompany);
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fTitle);

    String tempCompany = null, tempTitle = null;

    while(br1.readLine() != null)
    {
    tempCompany = br1.readLine()+ fCompany;
    }
    while(br2.readLine()!=null)
    {
    tempTitle = br2.readLine() + fTitle;
    }
    String tempFile = tempCompany + ", " + tempTitle;

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("F:\\companyTitleCombined.txt");
    char buffer[] = new char[tempFile.length()];
    tempFile.getChars(0,tempFile.length(),buffer,0);
    fw.write(buffer);
    fCompany.close();
    fTitle.close();
    fw.close();
```

Also one of my randomised file methods

```
public void loadCompanies(){

String[] strArr = new String[10];
int i = 0;

Scanner readInformation = null;

    try {       
        readInformation = new Scanner(new File("F:\\company.txt"));  
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("F:\\company2.txt"));
        System.setOut(out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not locate the data file!");
    }

    while(readInformation.hasNext()) {
        strArr[i] = readInformation.next();
        int rand = (int) Math.floor(strArr.length * Math.random());


        System.out.println(strArr[rand]);
        i++;
    }
    readInformation.close();
}
```

Any help you can give me to get rid of these unwanted outputs would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

**Example of output:**

**File 1:**
name1
name2
name3

**File 2:**
company1
company2
company3

**Combination of randomised File1 + File2 =  File3:**

name3, company2

name1, company1

name2, company3

Comment: Read into the `toString()` method in Java.

Comment: The `ios` tag should probably be removed from this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do read all the lines but you only store the last one in a variable.
Every assignment of the form `tempCompany = br1.readLine()+ fCompany;` throws away the previous value of `tempCompany`.  Also the `+ fCompany` part makes no sense, it adds a string representation of the `FileReader` (i.e. "java.io.FileReader@d80ba6ff") to the line and by your post you do not want that; you should just remove it.

Since you want to perform some operation on all the lines you should store them in a list.
Before `String tempCompany = null, tempTitle = null;` add

```
List<String> companies = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And change the loops to:

```
tempCompany = br1.readLine();
while(tempCompany != null)
{
    companies.add(tempCompany);
    tempCompany = br1.readLine();
}

tempTitle = br2.readLine();
while(tempTitle != null)
{
    titles.add(tempTitle);
    tempTitle = br1.readLine();
}
```

Now you will need to shuffle both lists:

```
Collections.shuffle(companies);
Collections.shuffle(titles);
```

For your desired output you will need to make sure that the lists are of equal length.
Also your input files do not seem to be split by line breaks but by spaces so `readLine` might not provide what you want.  If that is the case will either have to use the `split`-method from `String` or move to something like `StreamTokenizer`.

After that you can write the output file.  Just concatenate the strings of equal index from the two lists.